# Template class and derived classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, header-files

I have templated `MyDatabase` class and two derived classes `Database_A` and `Database_B`. I have another class `C` which is using `Database_A` and `Database_B`. So, whenever I am including headers of both derived class (`Database_A` and `Database_B`) in class `C`, it gives me this error "Redefinition of `MyDatabase`". My guessing is, because both derived class (`Database_A` and `Database_B`) are dragging template class `MyDatabase`, it could be the reason for redefinition of `MyDatabase`. But I don't know how to resolve this problem.

My code:

```
 template <typename U, class T> class My_DataBase {
     protected:
     std::map<U,T> Container
     public:
     void add();
     T* getNameToPointer(string key);
 };

 class Database_A: public My_Database <string,A> {
     add();
     A* getNameToPointer(name);
 };

 class Database_B: public My_DataBase <string,B> {
     add();
     B* getNameToPointer(name);
 };

 class C {
     private:
     Database_A Db_A;    // drage template class on back_end
     Database_B Db_B;    // drage template class on back_end
 };
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show us a complete minimal example. And this is not C, this is C++.

Comment: Simple explanation would be, I have template class A and two derived classes B and C. Now i have another class D which is using both classes B & C. So whenever i am including header files of B & C in D, it give me error of redefinition of class A. So how to avoid this problem??? Thank you

Comment: update your question with the header files please.

Comment: Whenever i am using header file of B or C, it does not give any error. But including both header files at a time gives error of redefinition for template class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have two header files, where each header file contains the base class and a dereived class. That's why you get a redefinition error.

To avoid this issue do this: Use three header files and include guards. The base class will be in one header file, named "My_DataBase.h". The two other headers files (one for every dereived class) will include "My_DataBase.h".

However, since you may want to include both header files (of the derived classes), you need to make use of the include guards to avoid redefinition of the base class.

So here is an example:

My_DataBase.h

```
#ifndef MY_DATABASE_H
#define MY_DATABASE_H
template <typename U, class T> class My_DataBase {
 protected:
 std::map<U,T> Container
 public:
 void add();
 T* getNameToPointer(string key);
}
#endif
```

Database_A.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_A_H
#define DATABASE_A_H

#include "My_DataBase.h"

class Database_A: public My_Database <string,A> {
 add();
 A* getNameToPointer(name);
}
```

Database_B.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_B_H
#define DATABASE_B_H

#include "My_DataBase.h"

class Database_B:public My_DataBase <string,B> {
  add();
  B* getNameToPointer(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent header files from multiple inclusion.
You can do this either by specifiying `#pragma once` instruction on the top of your header files (however I think this is Microsoft specific).
A better way is to surround your header file by code similar to the following :

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_FILENAME
#define MYHEADER_FILENAME
/// whatever contained in your header file
...
#endif // MYHEADER_FILENAME
```

Comment: `#pragma once` is technically compiler-specific, but in practice works on nearly every compiler e.g. Visual Studio, GCC, Clang.